# How to Select New DataTableRow in DataGridView

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, datatable

I am trying to select a newly added item in the DataGridView which is bound to a DataTable of items. I know we can loop through the DataGridView and find it...

**Select Row (DataGridView Loop)**

```
Private Sub SelectNewDgvItem(ByVal Item As clsItem, ByVal Dgv As DataGridView)
    For each r as DataGridViewRow In Dgv.Rows
        If r.Cells("PK_Item").Value = Item.PK_Item Then
           r.Selected()

           'Ensures visibility of the row if r.Cells("PK_Item") is visible
           Dgv.CurrentCell = r.Cells("PK_Item") 
           Exit For
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

---

I'm trying to figure out if we can select the DataGridView row using the DataTable

Comment: You sure can, just find the index of the row in your datatable and then set the selected row in the datagridview.

Comment: @MrCoDeXeR, that's not necessarily true.  If the data has been sorted and/or filtered then the index in the grid will likely not match the index in the table.

Comment: Of course, but he didn't say anything about it being sorted or filtered at that. If that's true doing what I said is fine.

Comment: Besides, if he does decide to filter or sort, this can be done beforehand then the select. Afterwards if he does that, then the index would definitely not be the same.

Comment: Yea sorry I forgot to mention that it should do it for sorted and not sorted data. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The proper way would be to bind the `DataTable` to a `BindingSource` and then bind the `BindingSource` to the `DataGridView`.  You can then call the `Find` method of the `BindingSource` to get the index of a row, which may or may not match the index of the corresponding row in the original `DataTable`.  You can then use that index to get a `DataGridViewRow` from the `Rows` collection of the grid and/or you can assign it to the `Position` property of the `BindingSource` to make that the current row in the UI.  This is just one example of why you should generally use a `BindingSource` when binding in WinForms.